# Can't get svnant tasks to work with ant 1.7.1, svnant 1.2.1, java 1.6.0_17, and svnkit on windows xp

Tags: svn, ant, svnkit, svnant

I'm trying to use svnkit to access subversion from the svnant ant tasks with the following result:

```
BUILD FAILED
/path/to/build.xml:49: Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask.getClientAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask.execute(Unknown Source)
```

I've verified that all the appropriate jars are on the classpath including svnkit.jar and svnjavahl.jar.

I get the same result running ant within eclipse 20100218-1602 with a similar classpath.

Curiously the following java program that invokes the above class appears to work:

```
org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask task = new org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask();
ISVNClientAdapter adapter = org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask.getClientAdapter(task);
System.out.println(adapter);
```

prints org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.svnkit.SvnKitClientAdapter

Also, the subclipse eclipse plugin uses svnkit (the one that came with eclipse) just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this solved by adding more dependent jar files to the classpath.  More later...

Answer (score 0):

(update July 2012)

Actually tigris.org has released Subclipse 1.8.14, compatible with SVN 1.7

But tigris has not released svnAnt compatible with SVN 1.7
svnAnt is based on svnKit, but only svnkit 1.7 is compatible with SVN 1.7

I've explored "current development" source code of svnAnt, 
The svnKit library contained in /lib is stille the old 1.6.15,
that supports only SVN 1.6

So we should wait several months.

To check by yourself:

- goto svnAnt page > current development
- download the svnKit library under /lib
- open it (unzip) and look at the file "svnkit.build.properties"